# Capturing Keystrokes in Java without focus on a Panel

Tags: java, focus, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I was wondering if there was a way to trigger a `KeyEvent` with Java's `KeyListener` while the Java program is running in the background? I want to keep track of what keys are being pressed and save them for later use. Here is a sample of the code I am trying to trigger:

```
public static class Push implements KeyListener{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        //Save KeyEvent info here

    } 
}
```

I do have a way of saving the information that I want, I just need to trigger this event. I am using an invisible window to cover my screen. I can click through this window , so it gives the appearance of not being there. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: What ethical reasons are there for doing this?

Comment: This is a personal program. I want to eventually use it to create more advanced keyboard macros and shortcuts that will be accessible to myself no matter what program I am using. I also am interested in numbers, and curious to what keys on my system are used most often.

Comment: Java cannot do this.  Choose another language.